# Unify DB and API return types

Tags: java, android, observable, rx-java, android-room

I am wondering what is the best way to unify the response type returned from both a room db and an API. Basically I am trying to get a list of Movie objects

Because of the API response design, I have to wrap the results in a `Observable<MovieResponse>` object

```
data class MovieResponse(@SerializedName("total_results") var totalResults: Int,
                     @SerializedName("total_pages") var totalPages: Int,
                     @SerializedName("results") var results: List<Movie>) {

}
```

So, then I can store the Movies in a local Room database, so the result from querying the DB is a `Observable<List<Movie>>` object.

This is forcing me of having 2 different methods (almost the same) to subscribe to both the API and DB responses

```
private fun subscribeMovies(moviesObservable: Observable<MovieResponse>) {
    disposable.add(moviesObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<MovieResponse>() {
                override fun onComplete() {

                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                override fun onNext(movieResponse: MovieResponse) {
                    // do stuff
                }
            }))
}

private fun subscribeMoviesFromDB(moviesObservable: Observable<List<Movie>>) {
    disposable.add(moviesObservable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<List<Movie>>() {
            override fun onComplete() {

            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onNext(movies: List<Movie>) {
                //do stuff
            }
        }))
}
```

Any advice on how to deal with this properly?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you simply pass `movieResponseObservable.map { it. results }` as a parameter into `fun subscribeMoviesFromDB()`  ?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I could do that, but the problem is that the database does not store data with the same format as the API returns. As you can see the API return can be encapsulated in the `MovieResponse` data class, however the database stores one movie per record, so when I do a SELECT I cannot build a `MovieResponse` but a List. The root of the problem lies at the source, when the data is retrieved, and then it spreads down the chain back to the view.

Answer (score 1):

You could make some sort of class that extends what you need. I'm not sure about the physical subscriptions, but at the very least you could make a generic class that you can throw into the `subscribeWith()` function that's not redundant.

How about something like this?  (Sorry I don't know kotlin, so here's a java equivalent):

```java
public class MyObserver<T> extends DisposableObserver<T> {
    @Override
    public void onComplete() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(T response) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Then you could in theory call it in each of your subscriptions like such:

```kotlin
disposable.add(moviesObservable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(object : MyObserver<List<Movie>>() {
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew, I see your point, however that would not help with the core problem. I would still have separate calls in the ViewModel and Repository classes and two different physical subscriptions. I am not sure if that is even possible but what I would somehow need is to unify those return types, if that makes sense?

Comment: To unify the return types, you will have to have access to at least one of the endpoints.  If it was me I would analyze the return types and see if there is anything about them that is redundant, and try to refactor them to use a common type.  Keep using S.O.L.I.D. principles and keep thinking how you can make your architecture better.

Comment: Also I'm assuming your using Room for local storage for persistence until you can get updates from the API, why do you need to subscribe to your local DB?  Most likely all you need to do is use Room to store data in case you can't get updates from the API.  So you don't really need to listen for updates, just listen for updates on the API stream.  And if you can't get them, then use your database for app-start up.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the API, so I cannot change that. Good point about the local persistance, although I use it as a watchlist instead of as a "backup" strategy and the user can delete entries from a long click. I guess I will have to live with that "inconsistency"